# Date parameters for Google Finance API not working

Tags: python-3.x, request, google-finance

I am trying to pull over end-of-day share prices going back in time. The code below provides exactly what I need but it appears that that the year/month/day parameters do not work.

```
import requests

params={'q': 'NASDAQ:AAPL', 'expd': 10, 'expm': 3, 'expy': 2018, 'output': 'json'}
response = requests.get('https://finance.google.com/finance', params=params, allow_redirects=False, timeout=10.0)
print(response.content)
```

The closing price for this is `"l" : "178.65"` which is the most recent closing price (15 March) and not for 10 March as specified. I am assuming I cannot rely on this service as it is no longer supported by Google but would be good if someone can confirm if I am correct around the dates not working or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, up until this morning this used to work:

http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:msft&output=csv&startdate=Mar+15%2c+2018&enddate=Mar+15%2c+2018

I asked two other people to confirm on different ISPs and we all get the same error message:

> We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now. See Google Help for more information.

Comment: Note: The grammatically incorrect "enter code here" was likely the actual message at the time.

Comment: @user16217248 I most likely copy and pasted whatever message was on the screen. Unless you have information that says otherwise, I'll leave it that way.

Comment: The enter code here is the placeholder text for Stack Overflow when you click the code format button, I believe. It most certainly is not part of the Google automated queries message.

Comment: @user16217248 Fair enough. Maybe I accidentally clicked the button after pasting the message, probably looking for the "quote" button. I will update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

same here:
https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=AAPL&output=csv

it looks like google close finance api or change path.

Answer (score 1):

This URL still works:

https://finance.google.co.uk/bctzjpnsun/historical?q=NASDAQ:msft&output=csv&startdate=Mar+15%2c+2018&enddate=Mar+15%2c+2018

I recommend you to make a copy of the data ASAP though, because Google will probably close this other link soon.